# Shulman's Thesis on Characteristic Classes

Tags: reference-request, characteristic-classes, paper-request

I am trying to find a copy of H. Shulman's 1972 Berkeley thesis 'On Characteristic Classes'. I've seen it referenced in Bott's ['On the de Rham theory of Certain Classifying Spaces'](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82496263.pdf) but I can't seem to find it anywhere online. Does anyone know where I can find it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the full title of Shulman's thesis is "On characteristic classes and foliations"; a few libraries have it, see [WorldCat](https://www.worldcat.org/title/characteristic-classes-and-foliations/oclc/21923876?referer=br&ht=edition), it seems you can order a copy from [the British Library.](http://explore.bl.uk/primo_library/libweb/action/display.do?tabs=moreTab&ct=display&fn=search&doc=BLL01014395333&indx=1&recIds=BLL01014395333&recIdxs=0&elementId=0&renderMode=poppedOut&displayMode=full&frbrVersion=&frbg=&&dscnt=0&scp.scps=scope%3A%28BLCONTENT%29&vl(2084770704UI0)=any&tb=t&vid=BLVU1&mode=Basic&srt=rank&tab=local_tab&dum=true&vl(freeText0)=shulman%20On%20Characteristic%20Classes%20thesis&dstmp=1609760534323)